# Duplication of NTAG203 tags

Tags: nfc

I'm creating a system that uses NTAG203 tags to identify accounts. The tags are formatted in the following way:

An Android app reads the tag's unique id.

The tag id is sent to a web server.

The web server creates a new account record, create a hash and salt from a combination of the new account id and the tag id and stores the hash and salt with the new account record.

The hash is returned to the Android app which then writes it on the tag.

When the tag is then scanned in future, the hash and tag id is sent to the web server for authentication.

My question is, how easy would it be to duplicate a tag like this? This would involve creating a tag with the same unique id, is this possible or can only NXP create the chips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating or modifying a tag such that it is identical is probably rather hard. However, emulating such a tag is not so hard. Several hardware platforms or schematics for them that can do this can be found on the Internet.

In general, it is not a good idea to make your security depend on the uniqueness of the ID or address of a piece of hardware that was not designed for security.

Comment: If I use the encryption feature of Ultralight C tags, does that mitigate the problem of cloning or emulating?

Comment: When you use authentication with Ultralight C, (part of) the contents of the tag is only readable after the reader has authenticated successfully. In this way you can protect the information used to identify the account. (BTW: the RF communication for the *read* commands is not protected by encryption. So theoretically it can be intercepted.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use NDEF record type 'U' well known category type 1 (drop the http:\) or type 2 (drop the https:\) and write protect the tag after a successful write - remember that the OTP also should be set for the NDEF aspect to work else you will have either a TAG DISCOVERED or TECH DISCOVERED (which means either it has content but not NDEF else is an empty tag.  Look up the NDEF standards for NFC, which are NOT part of the android framework, but is used by the framework.

Trap the tag ID (NDEF DISCOVERED or TECH DISCOVERED or TAG DISCOVERED) - if NDEF then do the server lookup, else treat as an empty tag - pass the Ident (remember its the 14A not 16A image value!) to the server for lookup, and on return perform a dead drop write (else display a button and let user press with tag present).  The encoding and decoding action of the NDEF NFC will be then as per the user phone setting, and automatic by android.

The 'emulation' aspect of a ISO14443 (a,b,c) tag by a device is still in its infancy, but if an Ident is present, has got a lock field and user area that is consistent then it is fairly difficult to duplicate - but add in some obfuscation and it gets interesting. There is a requirement that certain areas cannot be written to, or the lock bits undone, will give you an idea if the tag is being emulated or not.  The NTAG201/NTAG203/MIFARE tags are freely available, look on ebay.